# How to show that if there's a mapping reduction from L to its complement, it doesn't imply that L∈R?

Tags: computer-science, computability, formal-languages, turing-machines, decidability

I have the following prove/disprove claim:

> if $$L\leq_m L^{c}$$ then $$L\in R$$

I figured out that I can theoretically provide a counter-example where both $$L,L^{c}\not\in(RE\cup co-RE)$$ but couldn't find a mapping reduction between two sets with this property. I tried it with EQ and its complement, but couldn't find a mapping reduction.

Comment: this problem can be posted on theo comp sci: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @cineel: No. "Theoretical Computer Science - Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for **professional researchers** in theoretical computer science… We welcome you to join us in asking and answering **research-level questions**…
For **undergraduate-level questions** please visit [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexhange.com/)  which has a broader scope."

Answer (score 3):

Start with any non-recursive set $A$ of natural numbers. Then $L = \{ 2n \mid n \in A \} \cup \{ 2n+1 \mid n \notin A \}$ is a counterexample, because for all natural numbers $x, x\in L$ iff $x+(-1)^x \notin L.$  ($L$ is clearly not recursive, since $A$ is reducible to it.)

This actually shows that $L$ and $L^c$ are recursively isomorphic, which is stronger than what you were asking for.